# Backbone.js .on('add') to Collection is not causing a render

Tags: backbone.js

I am following CodeSchool's 'Anatomy of Backbone.js' and cannot get this to work on my machine.  There are similar questions, but they have a lot of extra stuff going on and, for someone brand-new like me, it's making it hard to learn.

Here's the code as simple/universal as possible:

```
var WorldEvent = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var WorldEventView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click' : 'focusEvent'
    },

    focusEvent: function(){
        alert('great.');
    },

    className : 'pin bounce',

    render : function () {
        console.log('did something');
        this.$el.html("rendered");
        return this;
    }
});

var WorldEventCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: WorldEvent,
    url: '/events'
});

var worldEventCollection = new WorldEventCollection();

var worldEventCollectionView = new WorldEventView({

    collection: worldEventCollection,

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
    },
    addOne: function(myEvent){
        var worldEventView = new WorldEventView({ model: myEvent });
        this.$el.append(worldEventView.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.addAll();
    }
});
```

**The good news is that if I call**

```
worldEventCollection.add(new WorldEvent( {<my data>} ));
```

... the new model is added to worldEventCollection - I've logged `worldEventCollection` and `worldEventCollection.length` to verify.

The bad news is that "did something" doesn't appear in the console and I see no evidence of a render.

Please help, I've wasted a ton of time on what is probably super simple.  Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Okay, I found one of my issues.  I needed to define a separate WorldEventCollectionView class altogether, so this was NOT correct:

```
var worldEventCollectionView = new WorldEventView({

    collection: worldEventCollection,

...
```

Instead, I believe one correct approach is:

```
var WorldEventCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this.collection);
...
```

And then:

```
var worldEventCollectionView = new WorldEventCollectionView({ collection: worldEventCollection });
```

Comment: Btw, is `addOne`method getting executed ?

Answer (score 0):

`WorldEventView.render` must end with `return this;` as per backbone view convention, otherwise chaining such as `worldEventView.render().el` will not work. Specifically, that will throw an exception since `render()` returns `undefined` and you try to access the `.el` property of `undefined`.

There's several other things that are not quite right about your snippet as well, but fix that first and see if you can take it from there. Generally in a view's `render` method, you want to populate HTML inside the view's `this.$el` and `return this;` at the end of `render` and really that's all you should be doing. Render has a very specific purpose and code that isn't following that basic idea and semantic belongs elsewhere.

Oh so this:

```
var worldEventCollectionView = new WorldEventView({
```

should be:

```
var WorldEventCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
```

Comment: I updated it and still nothing.  Per Cyclone's recommendation, I put a console.log() in the addOne method and it is not getting executed either.  I'm continuing to t/s on my own, but any more direction would be helpful.

Comment: It seems worldEventCollectionView isn't even being initialized ... ?